# How to handle HTTP requests with various path values in Owin Middleware

Tags: c#, httprequest, owin

**Context**

I have an Owin app that takes HTTP requests made to the URL path myapp/api/mgmt. I am implementing a middleware class that inherits from OwinMiddleware and overrides the Invoke method (as opposed to using a controller or some other mechanism of handling requests).

I would like to handle a few GET and POST requests such as:

- myapp/api/mgmt/queue/*id* (GET request to retrieve information about the queue with ID = *id*.)
- myapp/api/mgmt/queue/*id*?action=dequeue (POST request to dequeue an item from queue with ID = *id*.)
- myapp/api/mgmt/queue/*id*?action=enqueue (POST request to enqueue an item to queue with ID = *id*.)
- myapp/api/mgmt/queue/*id*/*itemid*/status (GET request to retrieve the status of the item with ID = *itemid* inside queue with ID = *id*.)

**Question**

I want to know how to extract *id* and *itemid* from requests that have those in the URL, as well as making sure that they are GUIDs. I know how to get query string parameters: `context.Request.Query["action"]`, but I'm not sure how to get the values in the path (i.e. each string separated by slashes). I'll present below how I'd do it, but I'm wondering if any of the Owin classes provide a more idiomatic/safe/efficient way of handling these requests.

**My attempt**

The way I would try to capture the various requests would be the following:

```
string path = context.Request.Path.Value; //path should start with "/queue/id"
if (path.StartsWith("/queue")
{
   string[] pathValues = path.Split('/');
   // first value in pathValues should be ''
   if (pathValues.Length > 2 && pathValues[1] == "queue")
   {
       if (Guid.TryParse(pathValues[2], out Guid queueId))
       {
           if (pathValues.Length == 3) 
           {
               // Now we know it's either (1) a GET for queue info, (2) a POST to dequeue an item from the queue, or (3) a POST to enqueue an item to the queue
           }
           else if (pathValues.Length == 5)
           {
               if (Guid.TryParse(pathValues[3], out Guid itemId) && pathValues[4] == "status")
               {
                   // we know it's a GET request for the item's status
               }
           }
           // All other cases return a 400.
       }
   }
}
```

To reiterate, I'm wondering if there's a better/more standard way of approaching this.

Comment: Why don't you use `WebApi` middleware?

Comment: I think that may be better because I can decorate the controller methods with attributes to make routing and value checking easy & safe, but I've been told to do it this way.